# How to use android databinding within a library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, shared-libraries, android-databinding

Is it possible to use Android DataBinding within a library project? I did create a library to be used for other people. Within this library I did use Android DataBinding. It did work on the same Android Studio project as a module, but when i install it to my local maven repo it wouldn't compile because of the generated files couldn't be found.
As I checked the aar file, i couldn't find the generated databinding folder as well.

The following error will be produced:

```
error: cannot access HeaderToolBarBinding
class file for com.test.library.shared.databinding.HeaderToolBarBinding not found
 Consult the following stack trace for details.
 com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for    
 com.test.library.shared.databinding.HeaderToolBarBinding not found
 1 error
```

Does anyone how we could solve this?

So,

```
 - Shared project
 ---> App (include library by compile project(":shared")
 ---> Shared library (with DataBinding enabled)

 - Project other people
 ---> App (include library by Gradle dependecies)
```

Comment: I guess you need to enable DataBinding in your project also where you are using this library

Comment: hmmm strange behaviour, because when i create a new project, include the library it will work. So for now, I will create a new project and copy-paste all.

Comment: @user447811 follow this blog post http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2016/07/android-data-binding-part-1.html

Answer (score 4):

For DataBinding to work in an application using your library, **both** need to enable DataBinding in their `build.gradle` file:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Comment: why the application consuming library needs to enable databinding ? can you explain the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Just update the gradle file of your app

```
dataBinding {
 enabled=true
 }
```